# Slack send attachment returning 500 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I am trying to send an attachment to a Slack web hook.

I have followed the API documentation and can send a simple message. When I try send an attachment I get a 500 error, I presume there is an issue with my payload but I cannot work it out for the life of me.

How do I get the attachment to post successfully?

```
import slackweb

slack = slackweb.Slack(url='WEB HOOK URL HERE')

slack.notify(text="Maguro is a sushi")

attachments = []
attachment = {
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
            "color": "#36a64f",
            "pretext": "Optional text that appears above the attachment block",
            "author_name": "Bobby Tables",
            "author_link": "http://flickr.com/bobby/",
            "author_icon": "http://flickr.com/icons/bobby.jpg",
            "title": "Slack API Documentation",
            "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/",
            "text": "Optional text that appears within the attachment",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "Priority",
                    "value": "High",
                    "short": False
                }
            ],
            "image_url": "http://my-website.com/path/to/image.jpg",
            "thumb_url": "http://example.com/path/to/thumb.png",
            "footer": "Slack API",
            "footer_icon": "https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/default_application_icon.png",
            "ts": 123456789
        }
    ]
}

attachments.append(attachment)
slack.notify(attachments=attachments)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing two required fields in your Slack message with attachments: `text` and `channel`. You also need to lowercase the value of the `short` field to `false`.

[See the corrected message here in Slack's message tester](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22You%20need%20this%20field%22%2C%22channel%22%3A%22C%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22fallback%22%3A%22Required%20plain-text%20summary%20of%20the%20attachment.%22%2C%22color%22%3A%22%2336a64f%22%2C%22pretext%22%3A%22Optional%20text%20that%20appears%20above%20the%20attachment%20block%22%2C%22author_name%22%3A%22Bobby%20Tables%22%2C%22author_link%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fflickr.com%2Fbobby%2F%22%2C%22author_icon%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fflickr.com%2Ficons%2Fbobby.jpg%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Slack%20API%20Documentation%22%2C%22title_link%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.slack.com%2F%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Optional%20text%20that%20appears%20within%20the%20attachment%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%5B%7B%22title%22%3A%22Priority%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22High%22%2C%22short%22%3Afalse%7D%5D%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fmy-website.com%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fimage.jpg%22%2C%22thumb_url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fthumb.png%22%2C%22footer%22%3A%22Slack%20API%22%2C%22footer_icon%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fplatform.slack-edge.com%2Fimg%2Fdefault_application_icon.png%22%2C%22ts%22%3A123456789%7D%5D%7D):

```
{
    "text": "You need this field",
    "channel": "C########",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
            "color": "#36a64f",
            "pretext": "Optional text that appears above the attachment block",
            "author_name": "Bobby Tables",
            "author_link": "http://flickr.com/bobby/",
            "author_icon": "http://flickr.com/icons/bobby.jpg",
            "title": "Slack API Documentation",
            "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/",
            "text": "Optional text that appears within the attachment",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "Priority",
                    "value": "High",
                    "short": false
                }
            ],
            "image_url": "http://my-website.com/path/to/image.jpg",
            "thumb_url": "http://example.com/path/to/thumb.png",
            "footer": "Slack API",
            "footer_icon": "https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/default_application_icon.png",
            "ts": 123456789
        }
    ]
}
```

Create a JSON structure including those two fields and your `attachments` variable, and you should be good to go.